# In a stored procedure, Need to find all the ancestors for all the nodes

Tags: mysql, database, recursion, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a two columns which are connected as parent_id and child_id.
like

```
(parent_id,child_id)
(NULL,38),
(38,15),
(38,17),
(15,10),
(15,5),
(5,2)
```

Now my output should be

```
(parent_id,child_id)
(NULL,38),
(38,15),
(38,17),
(38,10),
(38,5),
(38,2),
(15,10),
(15,5),
(15,2),
(5,2).
```

We are getting only the parents of each node. Not the ancestors of the node.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE find_parts_1(seed INT)
BEGIN
 -- Temporary storage
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _result;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _result (node INT PRIMARY KEY);

 -- Seeding
 INSERT INTO _result VALUES (seed);

 -- Iteration
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _tmp;
 CREATE  TABLE _tmp (node INT,parent_node INT,marks INT);
 REPEAT
   TRUNCATE TABLE _tmp;
   INSERT INTO _tmp SELECT child AS node,parent as parent_node,marks
     FROM _result JOIN nodes_1 ON node = parent;

    INSERT IGNORE INTO _result SELECT node FROM _tmp;

 UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0
 END REPEAT;

 INSERT  INTO _tmp(node) values (seed);



 SELECT * FROM _tmp;
END 
;;
```

This is the procedure we have written.

Comment: and what have you tried can you share us some of your code ? and where you are facing the issue('s) ?

Comment: @Mingebag I have shared the code.